# Android ListView within fragment doesn't refresh without a button click

Tags: java, android, android-listview

My `ListView` doesn't refresh its contents when I call the appropriate method unless the method was invoked with a button click.

The follow example code is how my test button works (temporary button to check to see if it was a problem with my refresh code):

```
testBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       exampleRefresh();
    }
});
```

And the method it calls:

```
public void exampleRefresh() {
    exampleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfItems());
    exampleListView.setAdapter(exampleAdapter);
}
```

This works fine.

However, if I call `exampleRefresh()` in the switch statement for a context menu, nothing happens. Again, when I click the test button, the `ListView` refreshes instantly. These are calling the *same* method, I don't understand the issue.

I have tried adding `nofifyDataSetChange()`, but it doesn't work. The `ListView` only refreshes when I invoke a button press.

It's also worth noting that even if I call the method on the invoke of a context menu, it refreshes. It does not do anything without an invoke, it appears.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming that the missing bracket in the `setOnClickListener` is just a typo, right?

Comment: Correct, thank you for pointing that out. I'll fix that to avoid confusion.

Comment: Since the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter` gets `Context` as the 1st argument, what happens if you pass it `MyActivity.this`? (subtituting `MyActivity` with the name of the containing activity)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to

```
exampleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>();
exampleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfItems());
exampleListView.setAdapter(exampleAdapter);
```

this should force it to clear and re-add the

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking `notifyDataSetChange()` from `exampleListView.post()` like this:

```
exampleListView.post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
         exampleAdapter.notifyDatasetChange();
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does provide an answer. I edited to make more clear what I meant @serejja.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it doesn't work unfortunately. For some reason I NEED to invoke a button press for the list to show the updates. If I do not invoke the test button, the changes are made, however they are not displayed until the app is re-opened, or the life cycle of the fragment is reset.

Comment: Is anything changing in your data?

Comment: Yes, something is being deleted from the database.

Answer (score 0):

if you are changing data in list and then you want to refresh listview then dont call setadapter method again. just call below method:

```
exampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChange() isn't changing anything which is why I called the adapter method again.

Comment: show me your that code. and are you changing anything in list data?

Comment: Yes, a database entry is being deleted.